# Can't access to express from console, windows 7 express lates

Tags: node.js, express, webserver

I'm new in node js, I'm triying to install globally express

```
npm i -g express
```

all completes, but when I enter
express --help
it says that it's not inside or outside command, however when i enter supervisor it runs OK. I looked into pathof express and there is no any .cmd file. If the problem is that. How should i fix it?

Please help.

Comment: If you're wanting the seed generator, it's `npm install -g express-generator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing npm install -g express will install express 4.
Express 4 separates the generator from express.
What you need to do is to run:

```
 $ npm install -g express-generator
```

Then it will work.

Comment: neolivz4ever, OOOOH thank you. and this aweasome community. It worked! when i type without $, please what means $ ? I can't understand.

Comment: That is an indicator advicing user to type command as a user, and not root (Administrator). In linux, $ - run as a user, # - run as a root. In windows # would mean 'Run as Administrator'. But those signs are meta-information for you, not to be typed :)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in express Readme [1], you need to install express generator separately, using following command:

```
npm install -g express-generator@3
```

[1] - https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/Readme.md